# oracle grand total row and column wise?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, oracle10g

I want a query that will count the row wise and column wise total,i have found the way to calculate column wise count but not getting row wise count.

```
select nvl(to_char(R.LTHT_FLAG), 'total') as a,
SUM(CASE WHEN p.STATUS_CODE='0' OR p.STATUS_CODE='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) K,
SUM(CASE WHEN p.STATUS_CODE='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) W, 
SUM(CASE WHEN p.STATUS_CODE='4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) C,
SUM(CASE WHEN p.STATUS_CODE='6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) R
from WORKASSIGNMENT P,RESOURCES R WHERE P.EMP_CODE=R.EMP_CODE
group by rollup (R.LTHT_FLAG);
```

the output of the following query is column wise count which is like.

```
A           K    W   C       R   Total
DEVELOPMENT 1   18  397      0     ?
HT         43   21  673      0     ?
LT        83    14  7955    60     ?
SLD      306    9   4621    24     ?
----------------------------------------
total    433    62  13646   84     ?
```

but now i want row wise count for this output

Please help me to get the sum row-wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add all the columns to get the total for each row.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'DEVELOPMENT' A, 1 k, 18 w, 397 c, 0 r FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'HT' A, 43 k, 21 w, 673 c, 0 r FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'LT' A, 83 k, 14 w, 7955 c, 60 r FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'SLD' A, 306 k, 9 w, 4621 c, 24 r FROM dual
  6  )
  7  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
  8  SELECT t.*, k+w+c+r total FROM sample_data t;

A                    K          W          C          R      TOTAL
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
DEVELOPMENT          1         18        397          0        416
HT                  43         21        673          0        737
LT                  83         14       7955         60       8112
SLD                306          9       4621         24       4960

SQL>
```

Above, instead of `sample_data`, put your current SQL as a **sub-query** in the FROM clause.

Comment: As i m new to this concept i did't understand any above code please simplify little bit, do not specify hard-core values

Comment: In your query, you are getting the columns `k,w,c,r`, make it as inner-query and in the outer query just add these columns.